# Cannot satisfy wrapper parameter for react testing library render function using TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom, react-testing-library, react-typescript

I'm trying to build a convenience function that allows me to pass a react component and have it render the component with all of the options and route specifications that I want that I pass it wrapped around a `<BrowserRouter>` for unit testing.

The problem is when I try to pass `Wrapper` function into react testing library's `render()` (see `rtlRender()` below), I'm getting an error from TypeScript stating the following

> No overload matches this call.
> Overload 1 of 2, '(ui: ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor>, options: RenderOptions<Queries, HTMLElement>): RenderResult<...>', gave the following error.
> Type '({ children }: Props) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<{}> | undefined'.
> Type '({ children }: Props) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<{}>'.
> Types of parameters '__0' and 'props' are incompatible.
> Type '{ children?: ReactNode; }' is not assignable to type 'Props'.
> Types of property 'children' are incompatible.
> Type 'ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'ReactChildren'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ReactChildren'.
> Overload 2 of 2, '(ui: ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor>, options?: Omit<RenderOptions<typeof import("/Users/myuser/dev/myapp/container/node_modules/@testing-library/dom/types/queries"), HTMLElement>, "queries"> | undefined): RenderResult<...>', gave the following error.
> Type '({ children }: Props) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<{}> | undefined'.
> Type '({ children }: Props) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<{}>'.ts(2769)
> index.d.ts(41, 3): The expected type comes from property 'wrapper' which is declared here on type 'RenderOptions<Queries, HTMLElement>'
> (property) RenderOptions<Queries, HTMLElement>.wrapper?: React.ComponentType<{}> | undefined

Here's my code

```
import React from 'react';
import { Queries, render as rtlRender } from '@testing-library/react';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { RenderResult } from '@testing-library/react/types';

/* Type Definitions */
type Route = {
  state: Record<string, unknown>;
  title: string;
  location: string;
};
type Props = {
  children: React.ReactChildren;
};

/* Helper Functions */
export function render(ui: JSX.Element, options: { route: Route }): RenderResult<Queries, HTMLElement> {
  const { route } = options;
  window.history.pushState(route?.state ?? null, route?.title ?? 'Root', route?.location ?? '/');

  const Wrapper = ({ children }: Props) => {
    return <BrowserRouter>{children}</BrowserRouter>;
  };

  return rtlRender(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper, ...options });
}
```

From what I understand, it's telling me that whatever `Wrapper()` returns doesn't fit the description of a React class component or functional component. This seems weird to me because you can tell from the code, `Wrapper()` should return a functional component.

I tried to assign `Wrapper()` to type `React.FC<Props>`, but TypeScript states that `React.FC<Props>` is not of type `React.ComponentType` which made me even more confused.

I'm still new to TypeScript so throwing in all these React types is confusing me even more. I'm hoping for some guidance on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`React.FC` type is alias of `React.FunctionComponent` type. The props of `React.FunctionComponent` is `PropsWithChildren` type which has `children?: ReactNode` property.  You don't need to create your own `Props` type.

The `options` parameter type of `render` function is:

```
export interface RenderOptions<Q extends Queries = typeof queries> {
  container?: Element
  baseElement?: Element
  hydrate?: boolean
  queries?: Q
  wrapper?: React.ComponentType
}
```

There is no `route` property, I think it's for the custom `render` function. But you need to use [Intersection Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) so that you can pass the `options` to `render` function of RTL.

```
type FC<P = {}> = FunctionComponent<P>;

interface FunctionComponent<P = {}> {
    (props: PropsWithChildren<P>, context?: any): ReactElement<any, any> | null;
    propTypes?: WeakValidationMap<P>;
    contextTypes?: ValidationMap<any>;
    defaultProps?: Partial<P>;
    displayName?: string;
}

type PropsWithChildren<P> = P & { children?: ReactNode };
```

The default generic parameter type for `RenderResult` is `typeof queries`, **NOT** `Queries`. This is the `Queries` interface:

```
export interface Queries {
    [T: string]: Query;
}
```

It's totally different with `@testing-library/dom/types/queries.d.ts`.

```
import React from 'react';
import { queries, render as rtlRender, RenderOptions } from '@testing-library/react';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { RenderResult } from '@testing-library/react/types';

/* Type Definitions */
type Route = {
  state: Record<string, unknown>;
  title: string;
  location: string;
};

/* Helper Functions */
export function render(
  ui: React.ReactElement,
  options: { route: Route } & Omit<RenderOptions, 'queries'>
): RenderResult<typeof queries> {
  const { route, ...rest } = options;
  window.history.pushState(route?.state ?? null, route?.title ?? 'Root', route?.location ?? '/');

  const Wrapper: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
    return <BrowserRouter>{children}</BrowserRouter>;
  };

  return rtlRender(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper, ...rest });
}
```